# Firebase 3 issue with queryOrderedByChild

Tags: ios, firebase

I have an issue where the following block of code returns values correctly on a firebase 2 app, but returns nothing on a firebase 3 app. I'm guessing that the issue is caused by firebase 3 needing the uid for each of the users to be filled in in the actual query where as firebase 2 didn't need that. Code is below, and screen shot of data layout also.

Has anyone else experienced issues like this? I know that firebase 3 is only a few weeks old so it's going to have some issues, but just hoping someone can help me out with this one.

Thanks!

```
    database.queryOrderedByChild("displayName").queryEqualToValue(friendDisplayName)
      .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually that displayName is a reserved keyword - this isn't anywhere in the firebase documentation that I could see, but as soon as you changed it to username or something it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little bit late, but recently I ran into the same issue.

My particular problem was not to be authenticated when running the query.

When you use .Value, all the childs of that node will be searched so no need to enter the uid, thats not the problem.

Hope this helps.